# Combine 2 lists according to compared object's variable

Tags: java, list

So I have got 2 object lists A and B. I will call merged list c. That is from the class Flights.

```
   public class Flights{
   String airline;
   
   }
```

Where
The list looks like this

```
  list<Flights>a
    list<Flights>b 
    list<Flights>c
```

The combined list should always have alternating element from A and B.
e.g. c = a(1), b(1), a(3), b(4). C also should have the following properties

1. The position of elements in C should be such that elements in A are compare to B where elements that have the same airline is placed beside one another. E.g. merged list = A.united, B.united, A.emirates, B.emirates and so on

By matching I mean placing the elements after the other

2. After completing step 1, it should then find the elements in A and B that were previously not added to C. Match all those elements to all elements from the other list. E.g. if a(5) wasn't added to the list previously, it will be matched with b(1-5)
3. Then, go through each element in A and make sure there is a match with all elements in B.

Example
Say A has 1,2,3 and B has 2,3,10, then the output as [2,2],[3,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1,10],[2,3],[2,10],[3,10]

The brackets mean each match.
My current code

```
List<Flights> secondaryFlights  // filled a
List<Flights> primaryFlights    // filled b
List<Flights> flightsList       // Empty  c
    for ( Flights p : primaryFlights) {
                for ( Flights s : secondaryFlights) {
                    if ( p.getAirline().equals(s.getAirline())) {
                        flightsList.add(p);
                        flightsList.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            while( !flightsList.containsAll(primaryFlights) || !flightsList.containsAll(secondaryFlights)) {
                
            }
```

Comment: You should try writing some code by yourself, and if you have a specific problem, then try to solve this specific problem. As it currently stands, this question is more like "please write this code for me" rather than "I'm trying to do `x` but I get this weird error".

Comment: @Laf I've updated my code

Comment: You didn't say why it doesn't works didn't provide a failing example.

Comment: @Fenzox Any update?

Comment: It works with the code I posted below

Comment: @Fenzox Mine works too(a bit faster) and can be made for `Flight` class as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with something like this

```
List<String>list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("tommy");
    list1.add("Alex");
    list1.add("Bryan");
    list1.add("Tom");
    list1.add("William");
    list1.add("Willy");

    List<String>list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("Alex");
    list2.add("William");
    list2.add("Candice");
    list2.add("Jane");
    list2.add("Parker");
    list2.add("tommy");
    
    List<String>merged = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    for ( String str1 : list1) {
        for ( String str2 : list2) {
            if ( str1.equals(str2)) {
                merged.add("[ " + str1);
                merged.add(str2 + "]");
            }
        }
    }
    for ( String str1 : list1) {
        for ( String str2 : list2) {
            if ( !str1.equals(str2)) {
                merged.add("[ " + str1);
                merged.add(str2 + "]");

        }
    }
        }
    
    System.out.println(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get more understanding from

```
String a[] = { "A", "E", "I" };
  String b[] = { "O", "U" };
  List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(a));
  list.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));
  Object[] c = list.toArray();
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

Comment: That doesn't do the comparison part

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your examples, you need matched once first and all unmatched ones in their order, so you can do like below:

- Create a `set` of second list and loop over the first list. If element in first list exists in the set, add them.
- For unmatched ones, create a new  set to avoid duplicating results. If the pair is un-visited, you can add it to the result. You can create the pair in a way it is convenient and doesn't overlap under any scenario. Taking your `1,2,3` and `2,3,10` example, I have separated integers by a pipe symbol(`|`). Java does seem to have `Pair` class too. You can use it if you like.

**Snippet:**

```
private static List<Integer> getData(List<Integer> l1,List<Integer> l2){
    List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(l2);
    for(int i=0;i<l1.size();++i){
        int x = l1.get(i);
        if(set.contains(x)){
            res.add(x);
            res.add(x);
        }
    }
    Set<String> pairs = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<l1.size();++i){
        int x = l1.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<l2.size();++j){
            int y = l2.get(j);
            int min = Math.min(x,y);
            int max = Math.max(x,y);
            if(x != y && !pairs.contains(min + "|" + max)){
                res.add(x);
                res.add(y);
                pairs.add(min + "|" + max);
            }       
        }
    }        
    
    return res;
}
```

**Driver code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(2,3,10);
        System.out.println(getData(l1,l2).toString());
    }
```

**Note:** You can replicate the same logic for your `Flight` class dataset. To compare strings, you can use `compareTo` method.